# FadeIn and fadeOut repeat

Tags: jquery, html, click, fadein, fadeout

When I quickly click a #div several times, fadeIn and fadeOut  is performed several times. I would like the animation is not repeated, if I quickly click #div animation perform only one time.

Code:

```
$("#div").click(function(){
    $("#information").fadeIn(1200).fadeOut(1200);
});
```

Sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.stop()`

```
$("#information").stop(true, true).fadeIn(1200).fadeOut(1200);
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/S48RU/